# How to remove the "users" module from meanjs stack generation

Tags: angularjs, meanjs, yo

The yeoman generators "meanjs" automagically installs a core and a user module when you do a fresh generation. My goal is to remove the user module and only use the core.

Any ideas?  I considered sharing code but I'm not sure it would help.

Thanks

More Info:
The reason i'd like to remove this is because the web application I'm creating requires ZERO user management

Comment: What version of `meanjs` you have downloaded: 0.3.3 or 0.4.0?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would simply be:

1. First make sure that you are able to run your code.
2. Delete the users folder.
3. Run your code, which will fail probably, and look at the errors.
4. Go through all the error messages and delete every link to the users module.

Note: this is applicable for MEAN version 0.4.X and above.